# I am facing "Your login attempt was not successful" Please try again. error while implementing custom membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-membershipprovider, multi-database

My requirement of application is single application & multiple databases for each client. So I implemented custom membership to achieve this. First I check user belongs to which Client the according to connection string of that client's db I dynamically set connection string & validate user.

Here is my web config :

```
<membership defaultProvider="EPMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <clear />       
    <add name="EPMembershipProvider" type="EfficientPeople.GlobalClasses.EPMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DBEntitiesConnectionString" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="25" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
    <!--<add name="EPMembershipProvider" type="EfficientPeople.GlobalClasses.EPMembershipProvider, EfficientPeople"  connectionStringName="DBEntitiesConnectionString" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="25" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />-->
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DBEntitiesConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="DBEntitiesConnectionString" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

CustomMembership Class :

```
public class EPMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);
        // Update the private connection string field in the base class.  

        Int64 ClientId = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["_clientId"]);
        if (ClientId > 0)
        {
            UserLoginML objUL = new UserLoginML();

            //string _dbMembershipConnStr = ManageSessionFacade._dbMembershipConnStr;
            string _dbMembershipConnStr = HttpContext.Current.Session["_dbMembershipConnStr"].ToString();
            //string connectionString = ManageSessionVariable.Current._dbContextConnStr;

            if (_dbMembershipConnStr != "" && _dbMembershipConnStr != "db_not_validate" && _dbMembershipConnStr != "db_not_exist")
            {
                try
                {
                    // Set private property of Membership provider.  
                    //FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    //connectionStringField.SetValue(this, _dbMembershipConnStr);
                    FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    if (connectionStringField != null)
                        connectionStringField.SetValue(this, _dbMembershipConnStr);

                    //Set role provider
                    var roleField = Roles.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    if (roleField != null)
                        roleField.SetValue(Roles.Provider, _dbMembershipConnStr);

                    //Set Profile Provider

                    var profileField = ProfileManager.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    if (profileField != null)
                        profileField.SetValue(ProfileManager.Provider, _dbMembershipConnStr);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

When I runs my application locally when I login with Client A[DB1]-User1 is logins successfully. But when I logout and trying to login with Client B [DB2] User2 it throws this error message :

> Your login attempt was not successful

When I again run the application & I do vice versa ie. login with Client B[DB2]-User2 it login successfully but when I try with Client A[DB1]-User1 in the same application run it throws the same error. But I am able to login with Client B[DB2] users.

When I debugged with breakpoints it throws error at

> ValidateUser(string Username, string Passwd)

method. ValidateUser method returning false.

I have tried lots of options but nothing works. Please guide me through.

Comment: Can you include the ValidateUser() function, since that's the function throwing the error?

Comment: I am using Membership class's method to validate :

bool Status = Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, Password);  

which is present in : namespace System.Web.Security  
public static class Membership{  
public static bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);  
}

Comment: Can you check if the user that it is beeing validated against changes between login attempts or if it is still stuck on the inital user.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. 

The user changes between login attempts & I have also checked the connection string being used by Membership is correct associated with that user. this method returning false when trying to login with other database users. But it works fine when the user who logs in first when the application is runs & all the other user in the same database.

Comment: theres 3 possibilities. Membership.ValidateUser will return false if the member is locked out or if he/she is not approved or if provided with wrong credentials. I guess you will have to see which one of the three applys to your case

Comment: I have checked all the possibilities you mentioned. Its not it completely not login. The issue is when I run the application the first user logs in successfully & other user which are associated with the same database are also able to login. But the users with different client database are not logging if I have logged in with any other database users.

I am using single application & multi-database. For each client there is a different database & there are no. of users in each client's db. When I logs with a database A user then all other database user can't login. If I rerun the app it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with SqlMembership's Initialize method. When user logs in first time it calls initialize method & set connection string. When another user tries to login it uses the same connection string. that's why its not validating. If we try to call SqlMembershipProvider's Initialize method It throws an exception of "InvalidOperationException : membership provider already initialized."

So I created the object of my custom membership & when I call Membership validate method by using newly created object I am able to set my connection string.

```
EPMembershipProvider myProvider = new EPMembershipProvider();
string configPath = "~/web.config";
Configuration config =     WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);
MembershipSection section = (MembershipSection)config.GetSection("system.web/membership");
ProviderSettingsCollection settings = section.Providers;
NameValueCollection membershipParams = settings[section.DefaultProvider].Parameters;
myProvider.Initialize("EPMembershipProvider", membershipParams);

bool Status = myProvider.ValidateUser(UserName, Password);
```

And it worked successfully. Thanx to Shri n all... :-)